# Flow to Typescript conversion for type mapping

Tags: typescript, translate

I have no idea how to use Flow, but I'm decently familiar with Typescript typings, however I can't make heads or tails what the following is in TS

```
//@flow
// Helpful port from TS
export type Pick<FromType, Properties: { [string]: 0 }> = $Exact<
  $ObjMapi<Properties, <K, V>(k: K, v: V) => $ElementType<FromType, K>>
>;
```

```
//TS (as far as I got)
export type Pick<FromType, Properties extends Record<string, 0>> = $ObjMapi<
    Properties,
    <K, V>(k: K, v: V) => $ElementType<FromType, K>
>;
```

Comment: In typescript, you can delete that line. [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) comes predefined by the language.

Comment: Ahhh makes sense, thanks a lot!

Comment: Keep in mid that TS does not support higher kinded types. See this issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213